# How to initialize a plugin from another javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

I have the following fiddle. On click of button 'scroll', is it possible to call the scrollTest function inside the plugin? Right now I am calling the whole test() again and hence it is creating a new test object each time I click on scroll button.

### My Code [ [fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/janae/0354g6fr/) ]

```js
    (function ($, win, doc) {
    'use strict';

    $.fn.test = Plugin;
    $.fn.test.Constructor = Test;

    function Plugin() {
        return this.each(function () {
            new Test(this);
        });
    }

    // TREE CLASS DEFINITION
    // =====================
    function Test(el) {
         var publ = this,
            priv = {};
        console.log("start");
        $('.test_button').click(function(){
            console.log("clicked");
            publ.scrollTest
        })

         publ.scrollTest = function () {
            console.log("in scrolltest");
        };
        publ.bindEvents= function () {
            console.log("in bind");
        };
        publ.fileter= function () {
            console.log("in filter");
        };
    }
    }(jQuery, this, this.document));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <h2>Hello</h2>
    <button class="test_button">Click me</button>
    <button class="test_button2" onclick="$('h2').test()">scroll</button>
    </body>
    <script>
 $('h2').test();
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the use of it inside a `$(document).ready();` block to ensure the script has loaded before starting to use it.

If you wish to have your code **only** run `onClick` for elements with the class *test_button2* you can use :

```
// include this only ONCE on your page.
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(this).test(true); // sends the flag to initialize the click() event once
   $('.test_button2').click(function(){
       $(this).test(); // action on every .test_button2 click();
   });
});
```

.. and replace ..

```
<button class="test_button2" onclick="$('h2').test()">scroll</button>
```

.. with ..

```
<button class="test_button2">scroll</button>
```

See the code below for the fix in action :

```js
(function ($, win, doc) {
    'use strict';

    $.fn.test = Plugin;

    var publ, priv;

    function Plugin(initialize) {
        if(initialize === true) {
           console.log("start");
           $('.test_button').click(function(){
              console.log("clicked");
           });
        }
        console.log("in scrolltest");
    }

    }(jQuery, this, this.document));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <h2>Hello</h2>
    <button class="test_button">Click me</button>
    
    <!-- onClick is handled by jQuery's .click() method -->
    <button class="test_button2">scroll</button>
</body>
<script>
   // this code should only be placed once on your page.
  
   var $test;
  
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $test = $(this).test(true);
      $('.test_button2').click(function(){
         $(this).test();
      });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: The problem is I have multiple object instances and hence I get ScrollTest run multiple time. Is there a way to call ScrollTest directly or check for the instance brfore calling the Tree() again?

Comment: @jenny what is the intention ?  If you want it to run only once, then put the `<script>$(document).ready( ... ) ...</script>` stuff only once.  If you want that action to occur on every button and only on button click, then remove said script tag completely as it's not required. Or you could do something a bit more fancy (modifying above code slightly)

Comment: I do not want to run only once. I have need the plugin to be called once and when I click 'scorl' buttton I just want scroll function to be called. The problem I am facing is , in console : Initially I get  console.log("start). When i   click 'click me' button, I get  console.log('clicked') once. But when I click 'Scroll button' and then clcik 'clcik me' button. I get console.log('clciked') twice. It think it is because the events  get bind twice.

Comment: I have updated the runnable sample to run the code only once, but apply to all.  As for the `in scroll` you are calling that method from inside the click() inside your plugin.  If you want scroll to be separate you can make it a separate method.

Comment: But I can not assign it to click. As per my requirement,  I want the plugin to be initialized on load as there are other functions in that. Also I want the page to execute scroll on load once . Then I make some changes to the page where I want just  the scroll function to be executed again. is there a way to reinitialize the plugin ?

Comment: @jenny - the plugin should be working now (doing what you described you wish it to do).  I removed some lines and left the code to the constructor to decide what it should run.

Comment: Where is value of isscroll coming from? could you please explain the concept behind this? what happens to the new Test(this);?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132078/discussion-between-jenny-and-kraang-prime).

Comment: `this` is always accessible from inside the init.   The value (i renamed to make it more clear)  --  `initialize`  which when you pass `true` will execute the hook - so only pass `true` once, and when you don't pass `true`, it runs your `scroll` code.